# Dynamically create tests in NUnit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

Using Nunit, I want to be able to write a test fixture that will read all the filenames in a particular directory and create a test for each file.

I could quite easily write one test method that scans through the directory and just does all the tests, but when I run NUnit I want to be able to see each of the tests individually.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I've found a way that fits my purposes

Have one test case, and mark it with the TestCaseSource attribute like so

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("GetTestCases")]
public void TestFile(string filename)
{
    //do test
}
```

Then write the GetTestCases to read all the file names in the directory

```
private static string[] GetTestCases()
{
    return GetAllFilesInCurrentDirectory();
}
```

Then when I start NUnit I get a list of the tests to be run (listed under TestFile).

Comment: Nice and simple. The attribute is also fairly flexible, as described in the docs (referring to v2.5.2) here: http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.2

Comment: NUnit rocks!! It made things simpler. I'm using this feature for integration tests

Comment: How to make it working in ReSharper test runner? It shows errors and fails in message boxes instead of displaying stack in testing session

Comment: @moudrick - You might want to make a new question specific to Resharper. A comment on a 7 year old answer is not going to get a response.

Comment: worth using nameof(GetTestCases) to make your test refactor friendly

Answer (score 3):

Try the [data driven test cases](http://code.google.com/p/nunit-extension-datadriven/) NUnit extension.

Answer (score 1):

If **you are not** going to be adding files to that directory over time and have a set of filenames to pass in as an input to a generic test, try using the [RowTest NUnit extension](http://www.andreas-schlapsi.com/projects/rowtest-extension-for-nunit/) (part of the std distrib post v2.4.7) - You'd be able to see each test case - input combination individually in the GUI grouped under a single node.

If **you are** going to be adding files to that directory, I'd write a single NUnit TestCase that loops over a list of files obtained at runtime and calls the generic test method with each filepath. Use a [collecting parameter](http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/accumulationToCollection.html) to collect failing test file names - at the end you assert. You wouldn't be able to see each test case individually but you'd have readable simple test code.

```
Assert.AreEqual(listOfFailedFiles.Length, 0, PrettyPrint(listOfFailedFiles))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little obscure but I have used a script in the past to generate code for me which I can then execute as individual test cases.